# How to copy backup databases to the \MySQL Server 8.0\Data file

Tags: mysql

I have experienced some connection problems with MariaDB 10.10.4 so I have decided to save a backup of my databases located in the Data file and change the version of mariadb to MySQL Server 8.0. If I take any database located in my backup data folder to MySQL Server 8.0 data folder. the database will not work. So I'm wondering if there is a way to manually add my backup databases. or if you can generate a schema of the databases. I don't know if the difference in versions between MariaDB or MySQL server are incompatible... So I appreciate any comments that may help me.

Comment: You will have to use `mysqldump` to export the data from MariaDB and import to MySQL 8.0. This is slower, but the files under the datadir are not compatible between these two products. You can't just copy the contents of datadir from MariaDB to MySQL 8.0 or vice versa. They were compatible at one time in the long past, but since 2018, MySQL changed a lot about the files.